# wmic linux client for DhcpServerPSProvider class

Tags: dhcp, wmic

I am using wmic linux client to get dhcp scope data from microsoft dhcp server running 2012 operating system.  I am trying to get scope statistics from this.

But it is not returning dhcp server/scope related information. Login goes fine.

```
$ wmic -d 1 -U <username> --namespace='Root\Microsoft\Windows\DHCP' //<ip>  "select * from dhcpserverversion" 

[wmi/wmic.c:196:main()] OK   : Login to remote object.

[wmi/wmic.c:200:main()] OK   : WMI query execute.

[wmi/wmic.c:203:main()] OK   : Reset result of WMI query.

[wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] OK   : Retrieve result data.
```

DHCP Provider WMI:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

WMI linux client:
https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Wmic-linux

I am able to get system information from WMI from this server. Its only DHCP Provider which is not working.

Appreciate any help on this.